# How to return hit term in ES ？

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to return only the terms that were successfully hit instead of the document itself, but I don’t know how to achieve the desired effect。

```
"es_episode" : {
"aliases" : { },
"mappings" : {
  "properties" : {
    "endTime" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
    "episodeId" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
    "startTime" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
    "studentIds" : {
      "type" : "long"
    }
  }
}
```

This is an example:

```
{
  "episodeId":124,
  "startTime":10,
  "endTime":20,
  "studentIds":[200,300]
}
```

My query:

```
GET /es_episode/_search
{
  "_source": ["studentIds"],
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "studentIds": [300,400]
    }
  }
}
```

The result is

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "es_episode",
        "_type" : "episode",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "studentIds" : [
            200,
            300
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

But in fact I only want to know which term hits. For example, the result I want should be studentIds=[300] instead of all studentIds=[200,300] of the returned document. It seems that some additional operations are required, but I don’t know
how.

I try to achieve my goal with the following query

```
GET /es_episode/_search
{ 
  "_source": ["studentIds"],
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "studentIds": [300,400]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "student_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "studentIds",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "episodeId"
          }
        },
        "id_select":{
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "key" : "_key"
            },
            "script": "params.key==300 || params.key==400"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the result for this is

```
"aggregations" : {
    "student_id" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 300,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "id" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : 124,
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

It seems that I successfully filtered out the terms I don’t want, but this doesn’t look pretty, and I need to set my parameters repeatedly in the script

Comment: Why not indexing one student per document? In this case, you'd have two documents and only the one with studentId=300 would return

Comment: Unfortunately, the structure of the document is defined in this way. I tried to use aggregation to return the key I needed, which seemed to be able to achieve the goal.